# Need help in list Java

Tags: java, list

Not sure how I can achieve this.
I have a object list, where it consists of multiple data example

```
ABC1231211
ABC1231111
ABC4562222
ABC4562456
```

Now I trying to seperate the list according to their code, which is 123 and 456, and add header and tailer to them. So my expected result would be

```
Head
ABC1231211
ABC1231111
Tail

Head2
ABC4562222
ABC4562456
Tail2
```

But the result I get is

```
Head
ABC1231211
Tail

Head
ABC1231111
Tail

Head2
ABC4562222
Tail2

Head2
ABC4562456
Tail2
```

Code

```
 @Override
    public List process(List<Detail> l) throws Exception {

        for (Detail d : l) {
            if (d.Code().equals("123")) {
                list = generateS(d);
            }
            if (d.Code().equals("456")) {
                list = generateR(d);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }


 public List<String> generateS(Detail d) throws Exception {

        try {
            list.add(new HDR("Head").getHeader());

            DetailL x = new DetailL();
            x.setType(d.getType());
            ....

            list.add(x.getDetail());

            list.add(new TLR("Tail").getTailer());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BatchException(DetailProcessor.class, ex);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You have no logic for grouping the elements by their code.

Comment: @Eran what is the best way ?

Comment: Please include more relevant code. What's `Detail`? What's `DetailL`? What's `DetailDTL`? Where do you parse the "ABC1231211" string to its different parts?

Comment: @Tony: group all `123`s together in a list, then call `generateS(List<Detail> detailList)` with the list as parameter and add header/footer to the whole group.

Comment: Because some code is missing is hard to say what you are doing wrong. Not sure what list from generateS is. Probably you should have 2 lists one for 123 and another one for 456 and add head and tail only once in these.

Comment: I for one think the code is reasonably well pared down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can use streams:

```
public void process(List<Detail> details) throws Exception {

    Map<String, List<Detail>> byCode =
        details.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Detail::getCode));

    byCode.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println(headerFromType(entry.getKey()));
        entry.getValue().foreach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(tailFromType(entry.getKey()));
}
```

with `headerFromType` and `tailFromType` returning "Head"/"Head2" or "Tail"/"Tail2", depending on the given type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implemetation that takes another approach:

```
private void go() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("ABC1231211");
    list.add("ABC1231111");
    list.add("ABC4562222");
    list.add("ABC4562456");

    String lastTag = null;
    int startPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String tag = list.get(i).substring(3, 6);
        if (!tag.equals(lastTag) && lastTag != null) {
            print(list.subList(startPos, i));
            startPos = i;
        }
        lastTag = tag;
    }
    print(list.subList(startPos, list.size()));
}

private void print(List<String> list) {
    System.out.println("Head");
    for (String item : list) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
    System.out.println("Tail");
}
```

Simply "If you come accross an element with a different tag, print the previous sublist". (And print whatever is left at the end since that sublist's printout is not triggered by a new tag.)

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a new head and tail for each element instead of adding to the already-generated list.

For each `Detail`, you should first check if the list exists, and if it doesn't, then call `generateS` or `generateR` as appropriate. If the list exists, you want to call e.g. `sList.add(sList.size()-1, d.getDetail())`. You'll of course want to replace the call `d.getDetail()` with the value that's supposed to go into the list or a method call that returns that value.

Then you probably want to use `list.addAll(sList)` to add the generated lists' contents to `list`.

Another solution is to generate the combined list on demand, and store the two lists separately. In that case, you would check if the corresponding list is null in the beginning of `generateS` or `generateR`, and initialize it if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new header and a new tail every time you call generateS or generateR but you should just create a new header once if you find a new code ( for example 123).

Solution: You collect your details into a list before you call generateS or generateR and put all the details from collected list into your DetailL.